# GRE tunneling in vmware vsphere guest

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, gre

Is it possible to make a GRE tunnel between a dedicated linux machine and a vmware vsphere guest VM (running debian wheezy)?

Comment: The answer to this question is "Yes". But a one word answer is too short for a real answer, so I'm suggesting that you elaborate on your question with details on why you think it might not work and what your actual question is.

Comment: Unless your question is concerning the actual virtualisation itself, the answer to any "can I... on a virtual machine..." question is nearly always the same as it would have been if the question was asked about non-virtual machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible.

A virtual machine runs the same kernel as a physical machine, has the same network stack, and the same concept of a network interface which its traffic goes in and out of.

The VMWare vSwitch is a software implementation of a network switch, so is the Linux bridge driver used in KVM.

If you search Google for "linux gre tunnel" you'll find many copy-paste examples.